# C# Timer to populate the database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, postgresql, timer

I am trying to retrieve the data from MSSQL and PostrgeSQL databases to populate it into a MySQL database on a regular basis (every hour).

Based on a research I've done, I would like to use a C# Timer to do that. However, I do not fully understand the way timer works. 
I declare it in the Page_Load, set the elapsed event handler and call a method from the event handler.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int duration = 100 * 60 * 5; //milliseconds * seconds * minutes

    // Create a timer with a two second interval.
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(duration);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

    timer.Enabled = true;
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    cf();
}
```

This works, but...

The problem is that this way the timer is being initialized every time the page is loaded. How do I create a timer which is initialized only once and keeps running from that moment without being reinitialized. Also, how do I handle the situation if the timer or a method fails - throws an exception, or a server goes down? How do I restart the timer then?

Any insight would help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you need to do this on a web project, it seems wrong to do this kind of job on a web page? Why don't you create a service application or a console application?

Comment: It is a Web Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to do this on a ASP.NET Web Page. The ASP.NET timer is designed for actions to occurs during the lifetime of a page before you navigate away.

IF you want to do long running work like this (i.e. a task once-per-hour 24/7) you would be much better off either:

- using an always on Windows Service with a System.Timer or
- using a Windows Scheduled Task with a 1-per-hour schedule, which kicks off a Console Application.

Another option, since you're task seems to be heavily related to database data transfer would be to use something like SSIS or another alternative ETL Tool (Extract-Transform-Load)

Comment: I am not familiar with any of those. I do not own the server, the app is hosted elsewhere. What would you recommend to use in this case?

Comment: ok. You may not own the server, but do you have the ability to put applications other than web applications on it. If you could write your code into a console application that just executes your code in it's `main` method, and then get the server administrator to setup a scheduled task for you.

Comment: The best way is using windows service as Eoin suggested but in your case (you want simple and fast solution) i suggested bellow to initialize timer in global.asax.

Comment: Eoin, I have never published a console application online. When I do it on my local machine, it creates a setup.exe file. How would this work on a hosting server?

Comment: The hosting provider does not offer scheduled tasks on Windows servers (which is used now). What would be a feasible way to create some sort of script locally to access this script on a remote hosting site every n hours?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers touch on this; I'll hit it over the head: Timers in ASP.NET are a bad idea.

The reason why has to do with the ASP.NET lifecycle. The very short of it is that an instance of a Page class (your codebehind) is instantiated for every page load. Once the resulting page has been output as HTML to the client's browser, the Page instance leaves scope and is destroyed. That means your Timer, set to run an hour from now, will be LONG gone before its Tick event would ever fire; a Page class can persist in memory for less than a second for simple pages.

You could work around this in certain cases by storing the Timer in the Session, which persists as long as the user's connection to the site does. However, Sessions usually time out much earlier than an hour (15 minutes is a common standard; sites with a high amount of private data, like online bank apps, time out as fast as 5 minutes).

So, I reiterate, do not use Timers in ASP.NET code. You can, instead, use a Timer in a Windows service running on the webserver (or app server) that will perform this data pull every hour. It can be given information by the web application, such as which users are connected, probably by accessing the database used by ASP.NET to authenticate/authorize online user accounts.

If it simply must be a web app doing the data refreshing, then I would keep a hidden field or JavaScript variable on the page somewhere indicating the next time that data should be pulled. Set a JavaScript timeout() for that time when the document loads, that triggers an AJAX call back to the server to run an event handler that refreshes MySql with the data from the other two DBs. Always verify that this data refresh really is supposed to happen in your codebehind (perhaps by keeping the same value in Session or ViewState), otherwise it's trivial to turn your own page's code into a DoS mechanism using a plug-in like FireBug or Chrome's built-in code editor. You can also fire the same event from Page_Load if the time to update has passed, covering yourself in cases where the user has JavaScript disabled; a page refresh by the user will pull the latest data if in fact it's time to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will stick with Console app and try to have my hoster to set up a scheduled task. The main problem is that I do not want to have the update triggered by user participation (I do not want user to have to visit a page to update the db).

Comment: ... Then you don't want this logic anywhere near your web layer in the first place; use a scheduled task or a service maintaining a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize timer in Global.asax. OnApplicationStart method.. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(v=vs.71).aspx

similar approach has been described here:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive

Comment: Don't do this. while it may work, A web application is not a suitable project for this kind of task.

Comment: I would work for sure. The best place would be separated background worker process (aka windows service)..

Comment: Eoin, what is the main drawback of this approach?

Comment: Main functional drawback (apart from design issue Eoin mentioned above) is in case your application is inactive for some period of time (there is no requests) and app pool will be recycled. In that case your timer will be activated (on app start) when first client request occurs.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you might want to move you initializer to were you declare all your other variables. Next you can have in your page load a function that sets your interval time to the time it takes to get to the next hour. Here is what i did.

```
    private void SetTimer()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        var nextFullHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(Math.Ceiling(timeOfDay.TotalHours));
        var delta = (nextFullHour - timeOfDay).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Interval = (int)delta;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

granted your scenario might be a little different, but that might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

One option assuming that you are limited by not having access to console applications, or windows services, or the local system to schedule a task would be to do the following.  My solution for a simulated timer when no timers are available.

Also you will need to assume that the timer doesn't have to fire exactly on the hour.

1. Add a table to your database that logs the last time the timer job was run.
2. After the page is finished loading, check to see if it has been an hour since the last time you ran your timer job.
3. If more than an hour has elapsed then execute the time job at that point.
4. When the time job starts log to the database that it was started, thus preventing another job from starting up.

Keep in mind that this is a very wacky way to simulate a timer when you don't have other options.